# SQL Server query to select only values not in a list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

As an example I have a table in SQL Server :

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |

and I have a list of values `1,2,3`

What is the query to select values of my list not in the table.

Expected result :

| Id |
| --- |
| 2 |

Comment: Use a `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: I'm trying with NOT EXISTS but without success so far

Comment: I can do the trick like that :
select Id from (select 1 Id 
union 
select 2
union
Select 3) as T
where Id not in (select Id from TableId)
But I think it's not the best option at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches

**Using Not Exists**

```
Select *
 from  string_split('1,2,3',',') A
 Where not exists ( select 1 from YourTable where ID=Value )
```

**Using a LEFT JOIN**

```
Select A.Value
 from  string_split('1,2,3',',') A
 left Join  YourTable B on A.value=B.ID
 Where B.ID is null
```

**Both Results are**

```
Value
2
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. STRING_SPLIT is the magic.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM id_table WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3);

Comment: No, I did this one but it returns all records of table which are not in 1.2.3, it means 5

Comment: It is better to write this answer in the comment

Comment: It is better to write this answer in the comment